# .htaccess If/Else statement doesn't work with HTTP_HOST

Tags: azure, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache-expression

This is my `.htaccess` file:

```
 RewriteEngine On

 <If "%{HTTP_HOST} == '<myHost>'">
   RewriteRule ^$ <url> [R=301,L]
 </If>
 <Else>
  RewriteRule ^$ <another_url> [R=301,L]
 </Else>
```

But it doesn't work and it seems like the `<If>` statement is ignored. I also made an echo from `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` in PHP and there I get the value I expected. Also, the `RewriteRule` is working if I remove the If/Else statement.

I'm using Azure Webapp with Apache/2.4.38 (Debian)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `if` and `else` block you can use `RedirectMatch` directive as it works with it . RewriteRule doesn't work because it overrides and conflicts with IF/ELSE.

```
 RewriteEngine On

 <If "%{HTTP_HOST} == '<myHost>'">
 RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ https://example.com
 </If>
 <Else>
 RedirectMatch ^/$ https://example2.com
 </Else>
```

Comment: "RewriteRule doesn't work because it overrides and conflicts with IF/ELSE" - `RewriteRule` does not override/conflict with `<If>`. It's simply that when `RewriteRule` directives are used inside an `<If>` block, the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ matches against the absolute filesystem path as opposed to the relative URL-path (as you would normally expect in `.htaccess`). See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68686987/369434) for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

The `<If>` statement is not ignored. The "problem" is that when used inside an `<If>` expression the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches the absolute filesystem path, not the requested URL-path that you are expecting.

The `<If>` block changes the order of processing. [`<If>` blocks are merged very late](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html#merging), after `.htaccess` files are ordinarily processed and seemingly after the request has been remapped back to the filesystem (ie. after the directory-prefix has been added back).

With this in mind, you could change your rules to the following to get this to work:

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == '<myHost>'">
  RewriteRule ^/file/path/to/document-root/$ <url> [R=301,L]
</If>
<Else>
  RewriteRule ^/file/path/to/document-root/$ <another_url> [R=301,L]
</Else>
```

Where `/file/path/to/document-root/` is the absolute filesystem path to your document root directory (where the URL-path `/` maps to).

Alternatively, check the URL-path using the `REQUEST_URI` server variable in a condition instead. For example:

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == '<myHost>'">
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/
  RewriteRule ^ <url> [R=301,L]
</If>
<Else>
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/
  RewriteRule ^ <another_url> [R=301,L]
</Else>
```

Or, check the `REQUEST_URI` var in the `<If>` (and `<ElseIf>`) expression(s). On Apache 2.4.26+ you can nest expressions. For example:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} == '/'">
  <If "%{HTTP_HOST} == '<myHost>'">
    RewriteRule ^ <url> [R=301,L]
  </If>
  <Else>
    RewriteRule ^ <another_url> [R=301,L]
  </Else>
</If>
```

Or, use a mod_alias `RedirectMatch` directive inside the `<If>` expression, as suggested in @AmitVerma's answer. The mod_alias `RedirectMatch` (and `Redirect`) directives always reference the requested (root-relative) URL-path, regardless of context, so you don't get this ambiguity as with mod_rewrite.

Or, just use mod_rewrite, there is no need for the `<If>`/`<Else>` expression here. for example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =<myHost>
RewriteRule ^$ <url> [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ <another_url> [R=301,L]
```